# Intermittent "connection refused" between services

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running ~200 pods over 3 n1-standard-4 GKE instances. Traffic levels are low, so there's plenty of spare CPU and RAM on each machine. Frequently when services attempt to connect to one another the connection fails with "CONNECTION REFUSED". After a few retries the connections work OK.

If I look on the machines I see on two of them that `netstat -i` returns quite a few TX-DRP on the virtual interfaces.

I presume I'm running out of some kind of resource. Any ideas what this could be or how I can go about diagnosing/correcting it?

`kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system -a
NAME                                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
event-exporter-v0.1.7-5c4d9556cf-ndvrp                0/2       Evicted   0          33d
event-exporter-v0.1.7-5c4d9556cf-nr9z4                2/2       Running   0          19d
fluentd-gcp-v2.0.9-4cfhb                              2/2       Running   0          8d
fluentd-gcp-v2.0.9-hwp99                              2/2       Running   16         33d
fluentd-gcp-v2.0.9-v9zg4                              2/2       Running   16         33d
heapster-v1.4.3-699fc4bd5b-btgfk                      3/3       Running   1          8d
kube-dns-778977457c-b97cw                             3/3       Running   30         33d
kube-dns-778977457c-gpnj2                             3/3       Running   65         33d
kube-dns-autoscaler-7db47cb9b7-w5mph                  1/1       Running   8          33d
kube-proxy-gke-cluster-1-default-pool-522e7bcf-8h06   1/1       Running   8          33d
kube-proxy-gke-cluster-1-default-pool-522e7bcf-8p9w   1/1       Running   0          8d
kube-proxy-gke-cluster-1-default-pool-522e7bcf-kr1m   1/1       Running   8          33d
l7-default-backend-6497bcdb4d-zbvrn                   1/1       Running   33         33d
tiller-deploy-5b9d65c7f-drmsg                         1/1       Running   0          19d
tiller-deploy-5b9d65c7f-pdmp5                         0/1       Evicted   0          31d`

`kubectl get deployment --namespace=kube-system
NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
event-exporter-v0.1.7   1         1         1            1           33d
heapster-v1.4.3         1         1         1            1           33d
kube-dns                2         2         2            2           33d
kube-dns-autoscaler     1         1         1            1           33d
l7-default-backend      1         1         1            1           33d
tiller-deploy           1         1         1            1           31d`

Comment: More details may be helpful, but the place to start when it comes to troubleshooting is from the bottom. High TX-DRP means that outbound packets from a client to server don't have a proper rule so are getting dropped. Could be any of- pods not able to resolve service names to the correct IPs; DNS pods provisioned too low; pods restarting or being moved; service->pod selectors changing/incorrect.

Comment: The pods themselves are relatively static. They don't come and go. A few occasionally restart because things aren't working well. I don't believe they're getting moved (there's no pressure for that to happen). Messages are being sent directly to IP address and port number, so DNS isn't an issue.  The problem comes and goes without IP addresses, ports or running pods changing

Comment: I would be interested to know the software-defined network used by GKE; is that information available?

Comment: Agree with ^^; and the results of "sudo iptables --list" may be informative.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand `the software-defined network used by GKE`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in EKS and managed to resolve it.

The closest I got to the issue was running wget on the destination host. When running wget I could connect through loop-back every time but only randomly through kube-proxy (http://<destination-pod>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local).

My logs when connecting to cube proxy looked like this:

```
  Connecting to node.sandbox.svc.cluster.local (10.100.116.39:80)
  wget: can't connect to remote host (10.100.116.39): Connection refused
  Connecting to node.sandbox.svc.cluster.local (10.100.116.39:80)
  wget: can't connect to remote host (10.100.116.39): Connection refused
  Connecting to node.sandbox.svc.cluster.local (10.100.116.39:80)
  wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

I think in my case it was because of the Kubernetes version, I went from 1.18 to 1.19. Upon re-deploying the Helm chart I received the warnings:

`W0831 13:05:52.108306  183539 warnings.go:70] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress`

Updating the ingress to rectify the warnings resolved the issue. I no longer receive connection refused.

I'm not convinced this will fix your question since this version of Kubernetes was not released in 2018, but hopefully it will help others. GKE also can do automatic patching, so perhaps there was a similar issue.